# Euler Path and circuit

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is there a formal way to find all Euler paths in the graph. For example consider this graph:

[image]

This graph has $9$ edges and $6$ vertices.
By the definition a Eulerian path should not have repeated edge.
I tried different possibilities as:

$ABCFEDAF$, $ADCBEFC$, etc but none of them making euler path.

Comment: There is an Eulerian path if and only if exactly zero or two vertices have odd degree. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Constructing_Eulerian_trails_and_circuits

Comment: @RobertZ And note (for OP) that you can't have a single vertex of odd degree because each edge adds $2$ to the total of the degrees of the vertices, and so the total of the degrees must be even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Euler path is only possible if $0$ or $2$ nodes have odd degree, all other nodes need to have even degree - so that you can enter the node and exit the node on different edges (except the start and end point).

Your graph has $6$ nodes all of odd degree, that's why you can't find any Euler path.

In general if there exists Euler paths you can get all of them using Backtracking. Counting them really depends on the Graph itself.

Comment: One way of finding an Euler path: if you have two vertices of odd degree, join them, and then delete the extra edge at the end. That way you have all vertices of even degree, and your path will be a circuit. If your path doesn't include all the edges, take an unused edge from a used vertex and continue adding unused edges until you get a circuit (the even degree of vertices ensures you will always succeed). Then you can break off your original path at the vertex you chose, traverse the circuit and continue the original path. Continue until no edges remain.